# Rename tag [marvel-dice-masters] to [dice-masters]

Tags: discussion, tagging

We currently have two questions with the tag [marvel-dice-masters](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-dice-masters). Since this game came out, it's been expanded beyond Marvel's properties to include DC and D&D properties too. All properties are compatible and share rules, and game is commonly referred to as "Dice Masters". Thus we should update our tag and the questions.

Comment: I should point out that, unlike the [recent rename of Coup](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1331/3389), this one does have a tag wiki, and the OP doesn't have the reputation to edit the tag wiki of a new tag (or to edit questions). Regardless, I think that proposing a tag rename on meta before executing it is a good idea.

Comment: Since this has reached +5 with no downvotes or dissenting comments in the next day or two I was going to add a dice-masters tag to the 2 questions, remove the marvel-dice-masters tag, and copy/paste the tag wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added [dice-masters](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice-masters) to both of the questions that previously had [marvel-dice-masters](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-dice-masters) and removed that tag from the. I also copied the tag wiki over to the new tag.